# How did Hordak take over the Fright Zone?

Tags: she-ra

In *She-Ra and the Princesses of Power*, it is revealed that the Fright Zone used to be the realm ruled by the scorpion royal family, before Hordak took over. While talking to herself, Scorpia suggests that her family simply *voluntarily* handed control of the Fright Zone over to Hordak, a stranded alien soldier with anger issues and no particular talent for administration.

Of course, Scorpia could easily be wrong, and Hordak could simply have conquered the Fright Zone. However, we know that he had no Shadow Weaver, since she joined him after he was already established; no biological soldiers, almost certainly, since Horde Prime only employed clones of  himself and robots, and there are no Horde clones beside Hordak in the present day; and no working ship. He may have had a few robot soldiers, and his own considerable physical strength and ingenuity. Still, he would have been up against an entire (small) country, and one whose rulers would still have had access to the powers of the Black Garnet, making them more than a match for him in a direct fight.

So how did Hordak actually take control of the Fright Zone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evidence is sparse and the history is deliberately muddled by Hordak's lies and Scorpia's fantasies, but I think I can help to fit together a few pieces of the puzzle. During [Princess Prom](https://she-raandtheprincessesofpower.fandom.com/wiki/Princess_Prom/Transcript), Scorpia says:

> The Horde crash landed in my family's kingdom. We let them stay. My family gave Hordak our runestone, the Black Garnet.

Note that she says "the Horde", not "Lord Hordak". This could imply that Hordak already has a sizeable (presumably robotic) army at the time that he crashed. Or perhaps he managed to recruit a number of soldiers before being discovered by the royals.

> Scorpia: No one liked my family, even before we joined The Horde. I never really fit with the other princesses. I made them uncomfortable and they don't like that. They don't like me.

This could be Hordak's gaslighting, but it could also easily be true.
*Scorpions* are a tough sell compared to flowers, "Horror Hall" probably doesn't have as good a Yelp score as "Brightmoon", and while Mermista sometimes has a fish tail, Scorpia's family *always* have enormous crushing claws and venomous stingers. This may have predisposed them to be sympathetic  towards Hordak, obviously a fellow outcast.

Scorpia elaborates on her family's history with the Horde in the episode [Princess Scorpia](https://she-raandtheprincessesofpower.fandom.com/wiki/Princess_Scorpia/Transcript), explaining that her family formed an *alliance* with Hordak instead of directly ceding power:

> Scorpia: This guy...this is my granddad, the King. He was the greatest. I mean, that's what the Horde told me anyway, I don't remember him, I was too young. I have granddad to thank for my opportunities in life. He made the alliance with Hordak. As part of it, our kingdom gave up our Runestone... and... princess...

So, the official story isn't that they voluntarily handed their kingdom over to Hordak, but that they forged an alliance with him and/or his fledgling Horde.  It's never made clear what (if anything) her family gained or was supposed to gain as part of this alliance. Whatever it was, it must have been *extremely* valuable given what they were willing to give up in exchange. Access to Hordak's technology would be the obvious possibility. Or perhaps they were already is so weak a position that they felt they had little choice.

As you point out, this could be historical revisionism, or an "alliance" so one-sided that it was conquest in all but name. I think it's pretty obvious that we're meant to interpret Scorpia's claim that her grandfather was "the greatest" with more than a grain of salt. I think the most viable interpretation is that the Scorpion kingdom underestimated Hordak, took pity on him, and was manipulated and/or forced into making increasingly unfavorable concessions until he effectively controlled their entire kingdom.